# Callback returning train and validation performance

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, callback, keras

could you help me to understand how to implement a callback function which determines the performance of a model on the test **and** validation data?

I got a bit confused reading this from a nice [block entry](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/keras-callbacks/):

> len(self.model.validation_data) == 3,
>
> because validation_data[0] ==> train_x (that you input in
>   model.fit()),
>
> validation_data[1] ==> train_y,
>
> validation_data[2]=sample_weight.

As you can see, the blogger mentions that `validation_data` is here the training data. From the keyword "validation_data" which is also used in `model.fit` I would assume that `self.model.validation_data` returns the validation data and something like `self.model.x` would return the training data (as `model.fit(x= ...,)` is the input for the training data)

Could someone shed light on this?

Thanks in advance for your help

---

**edit:**

I checked with `dir(self)` if there would be something like an `x` for the training data. But indeed, there is only `validation_data`. Could someone explain to me how I can differentiate between test and validation?
Is `validation_data` always the training data used in

```
def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
```

and validation_data becomes the actual validation set when using ?

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
```

---

**edit edit:**

in [the same block](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/keras-callbacks/) the author talks about `self.model.training_data`
he found but could not retrieve. I searched for this but apparently, it was removed.

So my question may be more on point: **How can you load the used training data at the end of an epoch in a callback.**

Comment: did you found the solution? I have the same issue now. I need to get the training data at each epoch to plot the confusion matrix

Comment: done. I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite simple.

Before you do model.fit() you can stick anything to the model. 
I just sticked X_train and Y_train to it. You can here stick the validation or test data to it, whatever you want.

```
model.X_train=X_train
model.Y_train=Y_train
```

Then, you use those values with the sklearn library to calculate any performance (accuracy, f1, kappa, ... )

First, **add variables** to self to enable later appending each epoch result to the variable

```
class yourowncallbackname(Callback):
    def_on_train_begin(self,logs={}):
         self.val_f1=[]  #define the variable to collect results
         self.val_kappa=[]
```

then define what happens on the **end of each epoch** in the same class "yourowncallbackname" (on epoch end works best). Here you use the data sticked to the model (e.g.

```
model.x_train) to get the results from model.predict. 
     def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
         #LOAD DATA
         train_predict= (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.model.X_train)))    
         train_true=self.model.Y_train_jan           
         val_predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
         val_true = self.validation_data[1]
```

Maybe, depending on what you want to predict you have to round the predictions with .round

```
         val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.model.X_train))).round()
```

Then **calculate any performance** you like on the predicted data  (same as defined in on_train_begin)   for e.g. test and validation

```
        _train_f1= f1_score(train_true, train_predict, labels=...)
        _train_k= cohen_kappa_score(train_true.ravel(),train_predict,labels=...)

        _val_f1= f1_score(val_true, val_predict, labels=...)
        _val_k= cohen_kappa_score(val_true.ravel(), val_predict, labels=...)
```

To **collect them,** stick them now to self. This will stick to the callback itself which you can later call again.

```
          self.train_f1.append(_train_f1)
          self.train_kappa.append(_train_k)

          self.val_f1.append(_val_f1)
          self.val_kappa.append(_val_k)
```

This callback you have to **initialize** now wherever you want to fit your model

```
 callbackmetric=yourowncallbackname()
```

Then you can put it into the fit:

```
history=model.fit(...
                  callbacks=[callbackmetric])
```

If you now want to use the appended results per epoch you can call them as you would call a class

```
Yourcallbackresults.val_f1=callbackmetric.val_f1
Yourcallbackresults.train_f1=callbackmetric.train_f1
```

For completion, I will post **the total callback** class again. You just have to addapt the correct perfroamnce calculation with al its parameters etc.:

```
class yourowncallbackname(Callback):
       def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
              self.val_f1 = []
              self.val_k = []

              self.train_f1 = []
              self.train_k = []

   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
          #LOAD DATA
          train_predict= (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.model.X_train)))    
          train_true=self.model.Y_train_jan           
          val_predict = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
          val_true = self.validation_data[1] 


          #CALC. PERFORMANCE
          _train_f1= f1_score(...)
          _train_k= cohen_kappa_score(...)      

          _val_f1= f1_score(...)
          _val_k= cohen_kappa_score(...)

          self.train_f1.append(_train_f1)
          self.train_k.append(_train_k)

          self.val_f1.append(_val_f1)
          self.val_k.append(_val_k)


          print (" val_f1: %f  val_k: %f" %(_val_f1,  _val_k))
          return
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a different way, because I am using tf.dataset api iterator  as input to model.fit. So I used Callback to predict the output and accumulated all the predictions at the end of each epoch to do further computations.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. If you want to, you could post your solution for future people to find. Have a nice day, Jan